# Как сделать запрос к модели, имея ее название в виде строки?

Tags: python, django

```py
model_name = 'MyModel'
```

Как мне имея только эту информацию сделать запрос к модели?

```py
result = MyModel.objects.all()
```

UPD
Опишу ситуацию подробнее. В отдельном модуле лежит список, его смысл такой:

```py
my_list = [
    {'param': 'foo', 'model': 'MyModel'}
    {'param': 'bar', 'model': 'OtherModel'}
]
```

Мне нужно по нему проитерироваться и для вот этих разных моделей выполнить почти одинаковые действия. Ну, грубо говоря:

```py
from .my_module import my_list

for elem in my_list:
    result = my_list['model'].objects.all()
```

Может быть вы вообще скажете мне, что я делаю ерунду и предложите что-нибудь получше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD:**

```py
import myapp.models

for elem in my_list:
    result = getattr(myapp.models, elem['model']).objects.all()
```

Comment: интересно, не знал, что так можно)

Comment: Только `modname`, наверное, без кавычек.

Comment: @hoefling Спасибо за замечание, опечатался, уже исправил.

Comment: @nomnoms12 я правильно понимаю, что эта запись эквивалентна import MyModel as MyModel? А если эта модель уже импортирована в модуль обычным способом, это можно использовать? Или это вызовет конфликт?

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров Да, эквивалентна. Если она уже импортирована, то зачем ещё раз импортировать то? Проверить её наличие Вы можете таким условием: `'MyModel' in sys.modules` (перед этим `import sys`).

Comment: @nomnoms12 я обновил вопрос, чтобы было понятнее зачем мне это нужно

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров Тогда вполне можете использовать мой код. Функция вернёт Вам объект модуля, можете не присваивать его, а сразу использовать. Конфликтов не будет. Если модуль уже импортирован, то вернётся кэшированный объект.

Comment: не присваивать его, а сразу использовать - я правильно понимаю, что вы имеете в виду `__import__(modname).objects.all()`, например?

Comment: @nomnoms12 все, вижу, большое спасибо

Comment: @nomnoms12 что-то я рано обрадовался. Происходит ошибка `ModuleNotFoundError`.  Как будто программа пытается импортировать целый модуль с таким называнием. А ведь мне нужен не модуль, а просто класс.

Comment: @nomnoms12 А вот `globals().get(elem['model'])` срабатывает

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров Попробуйте код, я обновил ответ.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров Много опечаток я стал делать. Простите, устал видать :(. Я так понимаю, модели в `models.py`. Тогда обращаться можете по атрибуту к этому модулю. Меня запутало то, что Вы сами написали 4-ым комментарием про эквивалент этому коду. Вот я и подумал, что вам нужен модуль.

Comment: @nomnoms12 тогда возникает еще один вопрос :) models обращается к django.db.models, а как мне в этой конструкции обратиться к models моего приложения?

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров Этот код получает атрибут какого-то объекта. Вы можете указать любой. Замените `models` в импорте и в `getattr` на имя, по которому доступен Ваш `models` в коде. Я в очередной раз обновил ответ :)

Comment: @nomnoms12 это работает, а чем плох вариант с globals? С ним можно импортировать не модуль, а все классы из него или перечислить нужные модели, насколько я знаю в django обычно имеено так импортируют модели.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров, `globals` немного неочевиден. Если кто-то, кроме Вас, будет разбираться в коде, то ему придётся потратить время на то, чтобы понять, как формируется список и какие объекты из огромного списка глобальных переменных он собирается получить. Используя явное получение атрибута, мы отбрасываем сомнения. Также это защищает от случайного переопределения, так как модуль тоже явно указан.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что это хороший способ, но он работает. Можно найти нужный класс по имени в globals (если он конечно там есть, в мое случае предполагается, что он должен там быть)

```py
from .models import *
model_name = 'MyModel'
model = globals().get(model_name)
if model:
    result = model.objects.all()
```